Non-squarefree numeral systems with constant congruence speeds for nontrivial tetration bases
Assuming radix-$10$ (the well-known decimal numeral system), let $a,b,c,k,t \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be such that $1 \neq a : a \not\equiv 0 \pmod{10}$, and $t \geq \min\{\nu_5(c), \nu_2(c)\}+ 2$ (where $\min\{\nu_5(c), \nu_2(c)\}$ indicates the minimum between the $2$-adic valuation and the $5$-adic valuation of $c$).
Let $$
\tilde{v}(a):= \begin{cases}v_{5}(a-1) & \text{if} \quad a \equiv 1 \pmod{5} \\ v_{5}\left(a^{2}+1\right) &  \text{if} \quad a \equiv2,3 \pmod{5} \\ v_{5}(a+1) &  \text{if} \quad a \equiv 4 \pmod{5}  \\
2 &  \text{if} \quad a = 5 \\
1 &  \text{if} \quad a \equiv 5 \pmod{10} \wedge a \neq 5   \\ \end{cases}.
$$
Now, we consider a peculiar property of any tetration (iterated exponentiation) $^b{a}$ (i.e., $a^{a^{\cdots^{a}}}$ $b$-times) that I named the "constancy of the congruence speed"; basically, for any $b \geq \tilde{v}(a) +2$, the constant congruence speed of $a$ (let us indicate it as $V(a)$) is the positive integer that gives the number of new stable (frozen) digits at the end of the result by moving from $^b{a}$ to $^{b+1}{a}$, without counting the final digits of $^b{a}$ that were already stable at height $b+1$. It is interesting since $V(a)$ is constant as we consider the number of new frozen digits at height $b+2$ that were not already stable at height $b+1$, the number of new frozen digits at height $b+3$ that were not already stable at height $b+2$, and so forth.
Now, for any given $c$, I have constructively proved the existence of infinitely many $c$-th perfect powers (in detail, $c$-th powers of positive integers that are not perfect powers themselves) whose constant congruence speed is equal to $t$ (and also, for any given positive integer $m$, I previously proved the existence of infinitely many prime numbers whose constant congruence speed is exactly $m$ - see Theorem 3 of The congruence speed formula).
The general equation is as follows:
$V \left(\left(10^{k+t}+10^{t-\min\{\nu_5(c), \nu_2(c)\}}+1 \right)^c \right)=t \quad
(k,t \in \mathbb{Z}^+ : t \geq \min\{\nu_5(c),\nu_2(c)\}+2)$ (proof here On the relation between perfect powers and tetration frozen digits).
Hence, as $c \geq 2$ is given, $t = c$ trivially implies that all the $c$-th perfect powers of $\left(10^{k+c}+10^{c-\min\{\nu_5(c), \nu_2(c)\}}+1 \right)$ are characterized by a constant congruence speed of $c$ (since $c \geq 2 \Rightarrow c \geq \min\{\nu_2{(c)}, \nu_5{(c)}\}+2$).
Question. Assuming that $g > 1$ is a non-squarefree integer, if $a > 1$ is not a multiple of $g$ and $b > a$, is there any radix-$g$ numeral system with a squarefree tetration base $a_{g}$ such that the number of new frozen digits at height $b + 1$ that were not already stable at height $b$ is equal to the number of new frozen digits at height $b + 2$ that were not already stable at height $b + 1$? If so, by calling this value the constant congruence speed of $a_{g}$ (radix-$g$), does the chosen numeral system contain any $c$-th perfect power ($c > 1$) of $a_{g}$ whose constant congruence speed (radix-$g$) is also equal to $c$?
P.S.
Here is a Python code of mine to easily calculate the value of the constant congruence speed (radix-$10$) of any input positive integer not a multiple of $10$ (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1k8wAY5pRllHOzG4Y5YBYAaq1_6pLyTPG?usp=sharing).

I guess there is no constant congruence speed radix-$g$ as long as $g$ is a non-squarefree natural number, but I have not investigated the topic... and my original proof of the constancy of the congruence speed cannot be replicated for any non-square-free numeral system.
